# select record with any kind of writing a username / field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I want to create a sql statement which does accept any writing of an given name

```
select * from Mytable where username='Peter';
```

I did not take care in the database to write Peter the correct way. Now I also want to select records with this content :

```
PETER
PeTER
PeteR
peteR
....
```

using ADO and DELPHI XE 2  and MSSQL Server EXPRESS version.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` - case insensitive search . 
If the default collation of your database is not case sensitive you can explicitly make your query ignore case sensitivity.

```
select * from Mytable 
where Username COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS= @Username COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, if performance isn't critical, is to make each lowercase (or uppercase) before the comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER('Peter');
```

Comment: Like does not solve the problem, and having a function call in your join would be VERY expensive.  Better to do a case insensitive search.

Comment: @BillGregg: There's no JOIN in this statement; and I edited to note the performance implications.

Answer (score -1):

You could make both sides upper or lower case:

`where UPPER(username) = 'PETER'`

Comment: Having a function call in your join would be VERY expensive.  Better to do a case insensitive search.